# Changing screen color in ProgressDialog

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following code to display a ProgressDialog while data is fetched from the internet:

```
    loading = new ProgressDialog( context, ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL );
    loading.setMessage( context.getResources().getString( R.string.loading ) );
    loading.setIndeterminate( true );
    loading.setCancelable( false );
    loading.show();
```

and it works nicely. There's just one problem: Every other screen in my application has a blue background, and the loading screen has a black background (#000000 by the looks of it). This is particularly annoying when the data download is quick as it appears as a black "flash" to users.

Is there a way to change the black background behind a ProgressDialog (not the dark gray of the ProgressDialog itself)?

Comment: you should put the snap of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the black background of your activity then, you will have to use the async task and implement doInBackground() API and if you are looking for the background of the progress dialog then you will have to customize your dialog which should not be difficult.

Comment: Shaista: Thank you for following up. The dialog is actually already inside an AsyncTask (it's invoked in onPreExecute()). So maybe I have to set the background color for the AsyncTask itself? Do you know how I do this, considering that it's no an Activity?

Comment: Yes, you are right you have to do it in onPreExecute(), it should not be a problem. Let me also try it and will post it here, once i do it.